# Create a block between 2 fixed blocks

Tags: html, css

This is an angular app embedded with the electron.
I have 2 blocks

- A **title-bar** with `position: fixed`
- A **navigation-bar** with `position: fixed`

I would like to have a content-area delimited by the rest of the `width` and `height`. This is my code:

```css
#app-content {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: 27px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  border:5px solid #ce2e2e;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<app-title-bar></app-title-bar>
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<div id="app-content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

I'm having the following result. The left and top margins make the block overflowing at the bottom and right.
How could I fix it? I already tried to put margins at the bottom and right but nothing happens.

[image: app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `box-sizing: border-box;` to include the border in the 100% width and height, and use `calc(...)` for `width` and `height` as shown below to include your margins in the 100%:

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
}
#app-content {
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-left: 27px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: calc(100% - 27px);
  height: calc(100% - 20px);
  overflow: auto;
  border:5px solid #ce2e2e;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<app-title-bar></app-title-bar>
<app-navigation-bar></app-navigation-bar>
<div id="app-content">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Comment: fixed now - I added `html, body { margin: 0; }` to reset the default margins - now the red border is visible everywhere